# Error: No file selected with file upload control still give count value 1 in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I am using file upload control in asp.net MVC with multiple file selection option.
When I upload 2 items than there is no error and run perfectly.
But, when I select no image then give me count 1 in the controller view.
How's this possible.?

here is my modal

```
public class DieModels
{
    public MouldDetail MD { get; set; }
    public MouldSubData MSD { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase DieImage { get; set; }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> DieDrawing { get; set; }
}
```

here is my HTML Code

```html
<div class="col-lg-8" style="margin:0 auto">
    <div class="card card-wizard" data-color="rose" id="wizardProfile">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewDie", "Die", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @* @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OA.ID)*@
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-fill btn-round btn-fab" name="back" href="@Url.Action("DieDetails", "Die")">
                                <i class="material-icons">backspace</i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <h3 class="card-title text-center">
                                Die Detail
                            </h3>
                            <h5 class="card-description text-center">New</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wizard-navigation">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                                Detail
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link redirect" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                                Data Profile
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                                Attachments
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="step1">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MD.PCODE, new { @Value = Session["pcode"].ToString() })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group require">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.MOULDCODE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Die Number", Title = "Die Number" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.MOULDCODE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group require">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.CastingDie, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Casting Die No ", Title = "Casting Die No" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.CastingDie, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="border-checkbox-section">
                                                <div class="border-checkbox-group border-checkbox-group-default" style="display:inline-block">
                                                    @Html.CheckBox("CustProperty", (Model != null && Model.MD.CustProperty.HasValue) ? Model.MD.CustProperty : false)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.CustProperty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                                <label for="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Checked if this is customer property.">Is Customer Property.?</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group require">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.PARTNO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Part No. ", Title = "Part No." } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.PARTNO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group require">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.DESCRIPTION, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description ", Title = "Description" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.DESCRIPTION, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group require">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.DRG, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Drawing No. ", Title = "Drawing No." } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.DRG, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.Rev, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Drawing Rev. ", Title = "Drawing Rev." } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.Rev, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.WEIGHT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Weight", Title = "Weight" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.WEIGHT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.CastingDrg, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Casting Drawing No. ", Title = "Casting Drawing No." } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.CastingDrg, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.CastingDrgRev, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Casting Drg. Rev. ", Title = "Casting Drawing Rev." } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.CastingDrgRev, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.CASTWT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Casting Weight", Title = "Casting Weight" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.CASTWT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.Ref_Drg, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Other Drawing ", Title = "Other Drawing" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.Ref_Drg, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.Ref_DrgRev, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Other Drawing Rev.", Title = "Other Drawing Rev." } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.Ref_DrgRev, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("SupplyCondition", Session["SC"] as SelectList, "-- Select Supply Condition -- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control js-example-basic-single" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.SupplyCondition, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.SpInstruction, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Special Instruction", Title = "Special Instruction" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.SpInstruction, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="step2">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("MetalCode", Session["metal"] as SelectList, "-- Select Metal -- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control js-example-basic-single" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.MetalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MSD.MarkingOnParts, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Marking On Parts", Title = "Marking On Parts" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.MarkingOnParts, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.TotalPIN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Total Pin", Title = "Total Pin" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.TotalPIN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.PINRemarks, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Pin Remarks", Title = "Pin Remarks" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.PINRemarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MSD.MetalPinMarking, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Metal Marking Pin", Title = "Metal Marketing Pin" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.MetalPinMarking, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MSD.CastPartNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Casting Part No.", Title = "Casting Part No." } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.CastPartNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MSD.PartnoPinMarking, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Partno Pin Marking", Title = "Partno Pin Marking" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.PartnoPinMarking, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MSD.MouldAttachmentDesc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Extra Attachment", Title = "Mould Attachment Description" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.MouldAttachmentDesc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.REMARKS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Remarks", Title = "Remarks" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.REMARKS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.DropDownList("SCODE", Session["Supplier"] as SelectList, "-- Select Supplier -- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control js-example-basic-single" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.SCODE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MD.MOULDCAVITY, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Total Cavity", Title = "Mould Cavity" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.MOULDCAVITY, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.DropDownList("MOULDMETAL", Session["DMetal"] as SelectList, "-- Select Die Metal -- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control js-example-basic-single" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MD.MOULDMETAL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.DropDownList("MouldTypeID", Session["DType"] as SelectList, "-- Select Die Type -- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control js-example-basic-single" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.MouldTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MSD.DieContraction, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Die Contraction(%)", Title = "Die Contraction(%)" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MSD.DieContraction, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="step3">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label><h4>Die Image</h4></label>
                                        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new text-center" data-provides="fileinput">
                                            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail">
                                                <img src="~/Images/image_placeholder.jpg" alt="...">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail"></div>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="btn btn-rose btn-round btn-file">
                                                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select Die</span>
                                                    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                                                    <input type="file" name="DieImage" value="DieImage" accept=".jpg,.png,.JPG,.jpeg,.JPEG,.PNG" />
                                                </span>
                                                <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-danger btn-round fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label><h4>Drawing Images</h4></label>
                                        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new text-center" data-provides="fileinput">
                                            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail">
                                                <img src="~/Images/image_placeholder.jpg" alt="...">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail"></div>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="btn btn-rose btn-round btn-file">
                                                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select Drawing</span>
                                                    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                                                    <input type="file" name="DieDrawing" value="DieDrawing" accept=".jpg,.png,.JPG,.jpeg,.JPEG,.PNG,.pdf,.PDF" multiple="multiple"/>
                                                </span>
                                                <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-danger btn-round fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="mr-auto">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-previous btn-fill btn-default btn-wd disabled" name="previous" value="Previous">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-auto">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-next btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd" name="next" value="Next">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd" name="finish" value="Finish" style="display: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my controller code

```
 if (dm.DieImage != null)
        {
            string DieNo = dm.MD.MOULDCODE;
            string FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dm.DieImage.FileName);
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(dm.DieImage.FileName);
            FileName = DieNo /*+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff")*/ + Extension;
            //dm.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + FileName;
            FileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Die"), FileName);
            dm.DieImage.SaveAs(FileName);
        }
        if (dm.DieDrawing.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < dm.DieDrawing.Count(); i++)
            {
                string Drg = dm.MD.DRG;
                string FName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dm.DieDrawing[i].FileName);
                string Ext = Path.GetExtension(dm.DieDrawing[i].FileName);
                FName = Drg + i /*+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff")*/ + Ext;
                //dm.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + FileName;
                FName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Drawing"), FName);
                dm.DieDrawing[i].SaveAs(FName);
            }
        }
```

here I upload an image with the problem(Error)
[image: Error output image]

Comment: there is no javascript and jquery I use. data is submitted when the form is submitted

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Comment: @er-sho I update my question. please show and guide me

Comment: On another note: Don't use the `.Count()` extension method on the `List<T>` to fetch the count. It is based on `IEnumerable<T>`, which will iterate through your list. Instead, there is a `Count` property, which gives you the value immediately. So, please remove the parentheses.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is the actual problem, but you are specifying `value="DieDrawing"` on your file input. My guess is, you do not want to set a value attribute, since you don't want the control to have a default value, especially not one with the same value as the `name` attribute. This may be what's causing your issue. I assume, you actually wanted to set `name="DieDrawing" id="DieDrawing"` (id instead of value).

Comment: that is not an issue... I change that to id but still the problem is as it is

Answer (score 0):

I just created a small test project for this, and I can confirm that this seems to be the default behavior when using a `List<HttpPostedFileBase>` for uploads. However, if you check the elements, you will find that the first element is `null` when you do not upload anything. So, to work around this problem, I would simply replace your code

```
if (dm.DieDrawing.Count() > 0)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < dm.DieDrawing.Count(); i++)
    {
```

with

```
if (dm.DieDrawing != null)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var file in dm.DieDrawing.Where(f => f != null))
    {
        i++;
        // process file here
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your code but it gives me an error like " Index was out of range. "

Comment: When i select Multiple image...than it gives me error on this line......string FName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dm.DieDrawing[i].FileName);.....@Christoph Herold

Comment: Why don't you simply use `file.FileName`? `file` contains the "non-empty" uploaded file of the current foreach iteration.

Comment: where i have to use file.Filename.?